# How do I execute this query in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, database

Suppose I have a column with words:

```
orange
grape
orange
orange
apple
orange
grape
banana
```

How do I execute a query to get the top 10 words, as well as their count?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT word, COUNT(*) word_cnt
FROM your_table
GROUP BY word
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 10
```

The `GROUP BY` groups by values of `word`, the `ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC` gets you the rows with highest count first, and the `LIMIT 10` returns the first 10 rows only.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT   word, COUNT(*) AS n
FROM     `table`
GROUP BY word
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: nice.  I had a related question about limit and performance.  Does the query first get everything that matches and limit shows a subset of that?  in other words, is using limit bad for performance?

Comment: apparrently, no, at least sorting step is 'partial', see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/limit-optimization.html